# Discordjs join voice channel and says a something then leave voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want my bot to join the voice channel where the commanding person is located and say something then leave, I tried to do this but I failed. The bot joins the sound channel but does not say anything. How can I do that?

Codes:

```
    client.on('message', async message => {
      if (!message.guild) return;

      if (message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "bruh" ) {
        if (message.member.voice.channel) {
          const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
        } else {
          message.reply('First of all you have to join an audio channel !');
          const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
          connection.play(ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZIpFytCSVc', { filter: 'audioonly' }));
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bot is not playing that YouTube video because you did not tell it to since you put the `play()` method in the `else` statement, not the `if` statement where it belongs.

Also, when importing a package, it is important you do so at the top of your file, not within the code, this is bad practice.

```js
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

client.on('message', async message => {
  if (!message.guild) return;

  if (message.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "bruh") {
    if (message.member.voice.channel) {
      const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
      connection.play(ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ZIpFytCSVc', { filter: 'audioonly' }));
    } else {
      message.reply('First of all you have to join an audio channel !');
    }
  }
});
```